# Where is the QDialog result value stored?

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

If I have the `QDialog` result value as `QDialog::Accepted`, where is such value stored? And, what is the benefit of knowing such value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it by calling QDialog's `result()` method.

And it allows you to know if the user clicked "OK" or "Cancel" (or any similar option) on the dialog.